# Interpreting Gross-Pitaevskii Equation in terms of fluid dynamics equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

In problem 1 of [this](https://quantum.lassp.cornell.edu/sites/mueller-courses/files/p3317sol02.2018.pdf) problem set, we start with the Gross-Pitaevskii Equation

$$i\hbar \partial_t \psi(x) = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial^2_x\psi(x) + V(x)\psi(x) + gN \vert \psi(x) \vert ^2 \psi(x)$$ where N is the total number of particles in an atomic gas.

From here, we take the ansatz $$\psi(x,t) = f(x,t)e^{i\phi(x,t)}$$ and plug this into the equation. We then manipulate the equations and separate them into imaginary and real equations, obtaining $$\dot{f} = -\frac{\hbar}{2m}(\phi''f + 2\phi'f')$$ for the imaginary equation and $$\partial_t\phi = -\frac{\hbar}{2m}(\partial_x)^2 + \frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2_xf}{f} - \frac{V}{\hbar} - \frac{gn}{\hbar}$$ for the real equation.

From here, we can do two things.

First, we put the imaginary part in the form of the continuity equation $$\partial_t\rho = -\nabla \cdot (\rho v)$$ where $v = \frac{\hbar}{m}\partial_x\phi$ and $\rho = f^2$.

Second, we put the real equation in terms of the euler equation. $$\partial_tv + \frac{1}{2}\partial_x(v^2) + \partial_x(\frac{V}{m} + \frac{gn}{m} - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m^2}\frac{f''}{f})$$

From this, we compare to the euler equation and identify the pressure as $$p = \frac{V}{m} + \frac{gn}{m} - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m^2}\frac{f''}{f}$$

Finally, I present my two questions.

1. I am having trouble interpreting this pressure term. I see that the first two terms come from the interaction terms in the GPE, which is presumably saying the pressure felt by this single particle wave function is due to the forces of neighboring particles. However, I am not sure if this is correct or how to interpret the last term $\frac{\hbar^2}{2m^2}\frac{f''}{f}$.
2. From this problem, I think I can conclude that, when trying to model an atomic gas via single particle wave functions feeling interaction forces via the GPE, we see that the motion of the particles in the imaginary axis is described by the continuity equation and that motion of the particles in the real axis can be described by the euler equation. However, I am not sure why it makes sense that the motion is distributed across the axes in this way. Namely, is there an interpretation for the fact that the axes exhibit their respective motions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Gross-Pitaevskii equation and thus will not be able to meaningfully answer the 2nd question.

However, I can help with the 1st question. You have arrived at
$$\tag1
mp=V+gn-\frac{\hslash^2}{2m}\frac{f^{\prime\prime}}f
$$
This means that the pressure comes from the externally applied potential and the self-consistent density of particles at any location, which is great for simple interpretation. And yes, high density at any point obviously tends to push the fluid apart.

The last one with the minus sign, is form-equivalent to the KE term of the Schrödinger equation, except that this is only for the real part. Still, this is a happy result because you know that Bernoulli's principle tells us that KE increasing in a fluid robs the fluid of static pressure.

Actually, I do have comments for your 2nd question. This has nothing to do with Gross-Pitaevskii equation, because back when Schrödinger first published his equation, people also tried to split the wavefunction to real and imaginary parts. Bohmian mechanics did this and interpreted that quantum theory added a quantum force to the individual trajectories.

You are actually not splitting along the axes. You are splitting the wavefunction into amplitude and phase parts. That they allow such an interpretation, however, is likely not something we can make sense of more than taking it as a suggestive analogy. At least, I am not aware of stronger arguments.

Comment: I see -- I did not know of Bernoulli's principle, so that makes sense for the 1st question. thanks!!!